# XSL-FO is dead, is there an alternative?

Tags: css, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I was using Java & Apache-FOP/XSL-FO to create PDF documents.

However, it seems that XSL-FO is dead since 2012 or 2013, according to http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/201311/msg00012.html

they propose [CSS3-page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) as an alternative.

Is there a java library to create PDF documents using CSS3-page or is there an alternative to Apache-FOP?

Comment: dead != not being standardised/evoluing anymore

Comment: Yes. There is a big difference between a standard some interpret as mature for the intended purpose .. And dead. As a person who works for a commercial xsl fo vendor, I can tell you our revenues have increased the last few years and this year has seen even stronger growth than the last. We have been working on CSS3 solutions also but it lacks the maturity in print media to implement without 100s of non-standard extensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be presented with "the news of my death are greatly exaggerated" reply. XSL:FO is alive and kicking, not at last since nobody is messing with the specification for the time being. Could it be enhanced, sure.

To answer your question: Most PDF generating solutions don't use the template approach that made XML/XSLT/XSL:FO such flexible. In Java land you mostly will find:

- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) - GPL or commercial
- Apache [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) - Apache 2.0 license
- and a few [others](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries)

which has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java). I'm biased towards PDFBox (I was the first one to donate to the maker, when it was still an undergraduate's project), but actually like Apache FOP a lot.

Comment: why do you think apache-fop is "alive and kicking"? we are in April 2014, and the last release was on Oct 2012. their website mentions a feature about "rounded corners", which is available only in the trunk for quite a lot of time. I asked the mailing list one week ago to make a release (or whether should do my own), and i got no reply.

Comment: Looking at it from: where do I encounter it in production systems. So there is a vital interest to keep it alive. One reason for the popularity seems to be the lack of changed

Comment: I would be happy to provide you info on production systems. RenderX has over 5000 installations doing everything from phone bills to the US Budget.

Comment: Checking the website, there was a recent release of Apache™ FOP, here are the details: `version 2.1 was released on 15 January 2016` Also, according to that page, all the components are stable except for the SVG renderer which needs work. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/status.html

Comment: iText is AGPL nowadays

Comment: From the perspective of 2024, Apache Fop 2.9 was released in August 2023. Dead? Hardly.